Как загрузить fastapi на хостинг и присвоить ему домейн?
Я изучал устройство работы fastapi. Сейчас когда мне нужно написать сайт я бы хотел его видеть на fastapi библиотеке.
Но проблема в том что мои знания ограничиваются деплоем на vds, а в репозитории примеры похожие примеры с локально созданной машиной. Мне удавалось подключится к сайту по http к его ip 193.74.24.30 (с использованием порта 3000 вроде).
Как мне загрузить сайт на хостинг и изменять его домейн (к примеру test.com)?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
